# Connect headset to radio

Tags: rf, radio

I would like to connect a [headset](https://www.amazon.de/gp/product/B06XCS95NG/ref=ppx_yo_dt_b_asin_title_o06_s00?ie=UTF8&psc=1) to my radio (Cobra AM845.)

The Cobra radio has a 2,5mm audio jack and the headset has a 3,5mm audio jack. I made a PCB to connect the together as:

[image]

When I close solder jumper 1 and 2, I can hear the voice in the speakers.
When I press the pushbutton SW1, I can hear on the other side that there is something recognized, but I don't hear any voice.

How do I have to connect the ḿicrophone to hear the voice?

In this image the microphone gets shorten when the button is pressed. How should it work or is this button a normal closed button and opens when pressing?
https://pinouts.ru/images/treo600stereo.gif

Comment: What do you mean by `I can hear on the other side that there is something recognized`?

Comment: I hear noise is coming out from the speaker on the second side. I see also on the display that the other side is transmitting

Comment: The microphone in the original headset has only a Electret microphone with a capacitor and a resistor (330Ohms) in parallel. When I press the talk button, the output voltage of the radio drops from 2,7V to 0V (DC). Seen on the oszilloskope that there is AC signal (the voice). The amazon headset does not pull the voltage down to zero, but to 0,9V. So there is maybe something more in than only an electret microphone, but what?